# Fragment transaction sometimes throwing exception

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments

This part of code inside an androidx.fragment is throwing a few daily Exceptions, I have been investigating a lot but I cannot find the problem.

```
private fun addRatingWidget(ratingItem: RatingItemEntity) {
        val context = context
        if (context != null) {
            ratingContainer?.removeAllViews()
            ratingContainer?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            val promptLayout = RelativeLayout(context)
            promptLayout.id = ViewCompat.generateViewId()
            val ratingWidget = RatingWidget.newInstance(ratingItem, this)
            childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(promptLayout.id, ratingWidget)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss()
            ratingContainer?.addView(promptLayout)
        }
    }
```

Here's the Exception (I know is in this Fragment because of screen sessions recording)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x4 (unknown) for fragment a{14c5b38 (136a5a73-e15e-40b5-91d6-b8ae83f7f861) id=0x4}
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:25)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.findFragmentUnder(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onSupportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:6)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:7)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:4)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Most of the solutions I found are related to the difference between childFragmentManager and supportFragmentManager, but this is an androidx.fragment creating another androidx.fragment, so I think that childFragmentManager fits.

Does anyone have any idea of what could be happening? A try/catch won't catch this, no?

Is the only fragment transaction that is failing in the project.

Thanks,

Mauricio

Edit: Shalu T D, is that what you are proposing?

Thanks

```
private fun addRatingWidget(ratingItem: RatingItemEntity) {
        val context = context
        if (context != null) {
            ratingContainer?.removeAllViews()
            ratingContainer?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(ratingContainer.id, RatingWidget.newInstance(ratingItem, this))
                .commitAllowingStateLoss()
        }
    }
```

Comment: instead of dynamically creating the layout, can you inflate and do the same?

Comment: question edited, could you take a look? Thanks !!